# Apache Beam stateful ParDo Work token invalid

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, dataflow

I have a stateful DoFn that basically batches the elements that are coming and when the buffer reaches a certain size, the buffer is cleared and the elements are inserted into BigQuery. What I've noticed is that from time to time, the pipeline is raising an exception, the exception is not stopping the job to run. Below is the stacktrace:

```
Error message from worker: generic::unknown: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1213, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.process
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 742, in apache_beam.runners.common.PerWindowInvoker.invoke_process
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 867, in apache_beam.runners.common.PerWindowInvoker._invoke_process_per_window
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gp/pipelines/common/writer_transforms.py", line 140, in process
    self._flush_buffer(buffer_state, count_state, buffer_size_state)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gp/pipelines/common/writer_transforms.py", line 162, in _flush_buffer
    rows = self._extract_rows(buffer_state)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gp/pipelines/common/writer_transforms.py", line 197, in _extract_rows
    for row in buffer.read():
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/bundle_processor.py", line 510, in __iter__
    for elem in self.first:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/sdk_worker.py", line 1039, in _lazy_iterator
    self._underlying.get_raw(state_key, continuation_token))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/sdk_worker.py", line 846, in get_raw
    continuation_token=continuation_token)))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/sdk_worker.py", line 886, in _blocking_request
    raise RuntimeError(response.error)
RuntimeError: INTERNAL: Work token invalid
```

This is raised when the process method is called and it tries to extract the elements from the buffer, see `rows = self._extract_rows(buffer_state)`

The DoFn is implemented exactly like in the example https://beam.apache.org/blog/timely-processing/#example-batched-rpc

Comment: Are you running with https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/deploying-a-pipeline#dataflow-runner-v2?

Comment: @robertwb yes, I've set the `--experiments=use_runner_v2` when the job is starting.

Comment: Work is always retried on failure for streaming jobs, so if this is transient it should be OK, but I'll try to figure out why you're getting this error.

Comment: I've noticed that this is happening on long-running jobs, like a day or more and it'f not very often. Elements of my pipeline look like this `(key, dict)` and what I keep in the buffer is that dict actually. Now, from time to time and for reasons unknown to me, when an element comes in a ParDo, the key is ok, but the actual value is `None`. Looking at the logs showed me that the same element with the same key was actually processed in another bundle on another thread. Don't know if this is the reason, but havinf something like `if not value...` helped for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've confirmed this error is expected during work reassignments, e.g. when autoscaling. The work item will be retried on the new machine and the pipeline will continue processing correctly. (I agree the error message could be improved.)

Comment: Quick question tho, why it's always failing when it tried to read from the state buffer? In the last few days, this error accurs more often and sometimes the pipeline gets stuck

Comment: Reading from state is a case where the runner can't hide from you that the work has been moved. (Otherwise, it will simply wait for the bundle to complete and silently discard the results.)

Comment: If your pipeline is actually getting stuck, I would file a user support ticket.

Comment: Hi again, well, what I've noticed now, I've had a pipeline which encountered an error like this "Work token invalid" and after this error, both metrices "System Latency" and "Data freshness" started to increase a lot. Doint some digging, noticed that some processed events didn't reached BigQuery, because this is what the pipeline is doing. Do you know more about this? Job ID is `2020-12-30_22_10_27-11400116370140824357` if it helps.

I really need to understand if the problem is in my code or is something related to Dataflow.